# oAuth 2 google login - access_token and refresh_token

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token

As far as I understood access_token has a short life about 1 hour and then if the user wants to log on I should use refresh_token to take new access_token. What I observed in my tests is that even on the next day when I try to log on, google logged me in without asking me for authentication which is slightly confusing. (in this test i did`t use refresh_token)
Can someone explain to me exactly when and why to use refresh_token.

Answer (score 0):

I know probably this question is too old, just for future readers...

You have probably gmail or (any other google page) open in another tab. As long as there is an active google page you're access token will be refreshed.